# I need to get a specific value in html with beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

maybe you guys here can help. i’m trying to get a token in a script on a website with python beautiful soup but i’m stuck at one part. the request i make is

```
getpollsoup = BeautifulSoup(getpolldata, 'html.parser')
poll = getpollsoup.find_all("script")[0]
print(poll)
```

the response is

```
    (function () {
        var config = {};

        // Transaction details
        config.transaction = {
            token: "36374fb17a52c4d145a7f689d8d20f85ca9e3747acb89f95f9b592fd4a4cf757",
            date: parseInt("1623792179"),
            expiry: parseInt("1623792479"),
            expiresIn: parseInt("299"), // "Expires in" calculated based on Server time
            expiresAfter: parseInt("300"),
            challengeMethod:  "delegate-sca" ,
            phoneNumberTail:  null         };

        // MPI data
        config.mpiData = JSON.parse(atob("eyJtZCI6IjQwMjkyNzc1NDIiLCJ0ZXJtVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6XC9cL3d3dy5zaG9wZGlzbmV5LmNvLnVrXC9vblwvZGVtYW5kd2FyZS5zdG9yZVwvU2l0ZXMtZGlzbmV5dWstU2l0ZVwvZW5fR0JcL1dvcmxkUGF5LUhhbmRsZUF1dGhlbnRpY2F0aW9uUmVzcG9uc2U/bm89NDAyOTI3NzU0MiJ9"));

        // One-Time Code
        config.otcVerify = "https://retry.touchtechpayments.com/api/v1/:verify";
        config.otcResend = "https://retry.touchtechpayments.com/api/v1/:resend";

        // Poll
        config.pollUrl = "https://poll.touchtechpayments.com/poll";

        // Select
        config.selectUrl = "https://retry.touchtechpayments.com/api/v1/:select";

        // Macs
        config.macsConfirmUrl = "https://macs.touchtechpayments.com/v1/confirmTransaction";
        config.macsCancelUrl = "https://macs.touchtechpayments.com/v1/cancelAuthentication";

        window.ttConfig = config;
    })();
</script>
```

but i only want the token in this case:  token: "36374fb17a52c4d145a7f689d8d20f85ca9e3747acb89f95f9b592fd4a4cf757"

help is appreciated

Comment: Is that the complete output of `poll`? Is there an opening `<script>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Regular Expression pattern to find the value of "token":

```
import re

# ... After creating the `soup`
poll = getpollsoup.find_all("script")[0]
print(re.search(r'token: "(.*)"', str(poll)).group(1))
```

Output:

```
36374fb17a52c4d145a7f689d8d20f85ca9e3747acb89f95f9b592fd4a4cf757
```

Comment: definitely the fastest way to get the token value.  Worth an upvote also (in 1 hour).  I will delete my answer too.

Comment: To also print the word "token", you can remove the `1` from `.group(1)`, so instead use: `.group()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need access throught JSON, there has an option:

```
import json

with open("test.json") as jsonFile:
   jsonObject = json.load(jsonFile)
   jsonFile.close()

tkn = jsonObject['config.transaction.token']
print(tkn)
```